# How to fetch submodules from GitLab in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, gitlab, github-actions

I need to fetch submodules stored on GitLab in a GitHub Actions workflow.

I can't see any options in `actions/checkout` that let me do this. It seems that the `repository` parameter only accepts a GitHub repository, and that the `submodules` and `token` parameters allow the workflow to fetch submodules, as long as they can be accessed using the same `token`, used to clone to `repository` itself?

https://github.com/actions/checkout

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you.
I just had the same problem, and the easy solution was to change the submodule to fetch using https instead of ssh. This only worked of course because the repo I'm pulling in from GitLab is public.